# Customising collection_check_boxes

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, form-helpers

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:post, :author_ids, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial) do |b| %>
   <% b.label { b.check_box + b.text } %>
<% end %>
```

The above code outputs the html as

```
<label tag>
    <input checkbox tag></checkbox>
    value of b.text
</label>
```

Can it be modified to output the html(i.e `label tag after input tag`) as

```
<input checkboxtag></checkbox>
<labeltag>
    value of b.text
</labeltag>
```

Tried various combinations with `collection_check_boxes` but couldn't succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:post, :author_ids, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial) do |b| %>
   <%= b.check_box %>
   <%= b.label %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you. It should be `<%= b.check_box %>` and `<%= b.label %>`.

Comment: Yeah don't know where that stray comment snuck in from.